# Pytest errors connecting to test database

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am running into strange errors I have never seen before running pytest where I am running my tests and nearly all are erroring out due to not being allowed to access the database.

This is a new error that did not occur last week so it isn't a local code change, but I am not sure exactly what happened.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Here is the error:

```
conftest.py:52: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:287: in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cacheops/query.py:271: in _fetch_all
    return self._no_monkey._fetch_all(self)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:1308: in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:53: in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1154: in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <django.test.testcases._DatabaseFailure object at 0x7fb361b2d2b0>

    def __call__(self):
>       raise AssertionError(self.message)
E       AssertionError: Database queries to 'test' are not allowed in this test. Add 'test' to pytest_django.fixtures._django_db_fixture_helper.<locals>.PytestDjangoTestCase.databases to ensure proper test isolation and silence this failure.

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py:146: AssertionError
_ ERROR at setup of TestAccountViews.test_can_edit_account_info_with_backticks[admin] _

db = None

    @pytest.fixture
    def slug(db):
        # delete these guys because there should only ever be 1 of each
        from apps.payments.models.ledger_models import TransactionCode
>       for code_object in TransactionCode.objects.all():
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it appears this was a versioning issue.

`pytest-django` https://pypi.org/project/pytest-django/4.3.0/ updated a few days ago and apparently this is a new error because of that. I don't see anything in their changelog: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html but dropping from version 4.3.0 to 4.2.0 did fix the issue.

Another fix to the issue was to alter `pytest_sessionstart()` to allow access to all databases in `conftest.py` like so:

```
def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    from django.test import TestCase
    TestCase.multi_db = True
    TestCase.databases = '__all__'      # here
```

Comment: Make sure to lock your dependencies and breaking updates won't happen behind your back...

Comment: @AKX yeah, I have it for everything else just didn't think it mattered for tests. Have already changed this in requirements.

Answer (score 4):

As per [Tests requiring multiple databases](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html?highlight=databases#tests-requiring-multiple-databases) in the `pytest-django` docs, it may now be possible (this worked for me on pytest-django version 4.3.0) to fix this by using the following pytest mark:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db(databases=['default', 'test'])
def test_my_code():
    ...
```

Where the list passed to `databases=` is a list of keys of databases you have defined in `settings.DATABASES`.

However it seems this area is subject to some change and may only partially be implemented, so YMMV.

Comment: I don't want to use default DB, I wat to use a different DB for testing how can i do that?

Comment: The list of databases passed to `databases=` is a list of keys in your `DATABASES` dictionary in your django settings.py file, so you should just pass the key of the database you want to use... if you want to use a different DB for all your tests then the simplest thing is to configure `DATABASES['default']` to be different when testing, which you can detect by looking at `sys.argv` or by using an environment variable